# Zend Framework css image just url with cotroller but not with the action

Tags: css, zend-framework, url, action

I'm learning Zend Framework... having this problem...

If I go to the URL www.mydomain.com/Index  will work FINE
but I go to the URL www.mydomain.com/Index/index  the CSS and IMAGE will NOT WORK...

OR for example:

If I go to the URL www.mydomain.com/Faq  will work FINE
but I go to the URL www.mydomain.com/Faq/test  the CSS and IMAGE will NOT WORK...

I don't understand why it work only if you specify the Controller and not Action...

In my layout.phtml I have:

```
<?php
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet(BASE_URL . 'css/style.css');
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet(BASE_URL . '/css/header.css');
    $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet(BASE_URL . 'css/footer.css');
echo $this->headLink();
?>
```

And in public/index.php I have:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
$baseUrl = $config->baseHttp;
define('BASE_URL', $baseUrl);
```

And for example an image in layout.phtml:

```
<img src="<?= BASE_URL ?>immagini/footer_info.png" alt="info" />
```

What's wrong?

Maybe the problem is the .htaccess or those stuff...  So I tell you more...

My hosting have the public root: public_html

Inside public_html I have different project folder.
Example:  Project1 and Project2 ( both with Zend Framework ).

In public_html/Project1 folder I have:

- Application
- Public
- ....
- index.php

  include 'public/index.php';
- .htaccess

  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule .* index.php

In public_html/Project1/public I have:

- CSS folder
- images folder
- js folder
- .htaccess

  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
- index.php ( another one )

  // Define path to application directory
  defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
      || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(**FILE**) . '/../application'));

  // Define application environment
  defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
      || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

  // Ensure library/ is on include_path
  set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
      realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
      get_include_path(),
  )));

  /** Zend_Application */
  require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

  // Create application, bootstrap, and run
  $application = new Zend_Application(
      APPLICATION_ENV,
      APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
  );

  $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(
          APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
      $baseUrl = $config->baseHttp;
      define('BASE_URL', $baseUrl);

  $application->bootstrap()
              ->run();

Thanks again...

Samuele

Comment: Post the difference in HTML here. Most likely you're using relative paths to access those resources

Comment: The problem is that the HTML is exactly the same...

Comment: Yes, this is most likely because the relative path will work from the index page and not the /index/action page because it is one level deeper

Comment: What is `$config->baseHttp` set to?  And what does the output HTML look like for the CSS and img paths in the working and non-working pages?

Comment: ChrisAnstey thanks for help me...  Anyway the answer of Tim Fountain worked fine for me...    :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `BASE_URL` is actually empty, so your issue is that you're using relative paths for your stylesheets and images, which won't work in subfolders. For example, on `www.mydomain.com/Faq`, a stylesheet include for `css/style.css` will resolve to `www.mydomain.com/css/style.css` which presumably is correct. On `www.mydomain.com/Faq/test` it will resolve to `www.domain.com/Faq/css/style.css` which is not correct.

The solution is to always use absolute paths:

```
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet(BASE_URL . '/css/style.css');
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet(BASE_URL . '/css/header.css');
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet(BASE_URL . '/css/footer.css');
```

(note the slash before css). Then, if you are setting base URL, make sure it does not include a trailing slash, e.g. `http://www.mydomain.com`. Everything should work correctly then.

Comment: Tim Fountain thank you so much...  Work perfectly...   :)  Just one question...  Dov you think is fine the project like this or there is a better way instead the double htaccess and the double index.php and the base_url defined in the index.php like a global variable?